# Corda observer keeps track of unconsumed transactions only?

Tags: corda

I was performing testing on corda observer node. On IOU issue, put call of flow for observer. same thing on IOU lender transfer flow (Flow for changing lender property to the new Party).

I issue IOU From partyA to PartyB. On observer node stateAndRef gets displayed too.

but when performed transferred IOU, no change gets displayed on observer node. It's still showing old state.

Does observer node keep unconsume states only in vault or consume/unconsumed transaction both?

below code is working for one flow IOU issue only not for other flow:

- I am referring IOU example [here](https://github.com/corda/corda-training-solutions/)

Below is the code I called from each Flow:

```
object BroadcastTransaction {
    @InitiatingFlow
    class BroadcastTransactionToObservers(private val stx: SignedTransaction, private val observers: List<Party>) : FlowLogic<Unit>() {

        @Suspendable
        override fun call() {
            val sessions = observers.map { initiateFlow(it) }
            sessions.forEach { subFlow(SendTransactionFlow(it, stx)) }
        }
    }

    @InitiatedBy(BroadcastTransactionToObservers::class)
    class RecordTransactionAsObserver(private val otherSession: FlowSession) :FlowLogic<Unit>() {

        @Suspendable
        override fun call() {
            subFlow( ReceiveTransactionFlow(
                    otherSideSession = otherSession,
                    checkSufficientSignatures = true,
                    statesToRecord = StatesToRecord.ALL_VISIBLE
                )
            )
        }
    }

}
```

I have checked logs for node getting not enough signature even after put call to observer flow just after finalityflow call...plz help in this regard?

Answer (score 0):

Finally found my mistake. In logs i got error "Insufficient signature corda". I had passes signedsignature after finalityflow but not passed finalityflow result to above mention flow.